# React Native Admob Test-Ads take a long time to load on an emulator

Tags: react-native, admob, react-native-google-mobile-ads

Is it normal for the test-ads to take several minutes before loading on an android emulator. I am specifically talking about the banner test-ads.

I am using react-native-google-mobile-ads with Expo.
The area where the banner would be displayed is empty for a couple of minutes before loading the ad. Is this expected behavior from an emulator-test-build, or is there a way to speed this up?

```js
import {BannerAd, BannerAdSize, TestIds,} from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

const adUnitId = __DEV__ ? TestIds.BANNER: 'ca-app-pub-   
xxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyyyyyy';

export default function App() {

  mobileAds()
    .initialize()
    .then((adapterStatuses) => {
      // Initialization complete!
    });

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
      }}
    >
      <Text>Test Ad</Text>
      <BannerAd
        unitId={adUnitId}
        size={BannerAdSize.FULL_BANNER}
        requestOptions={{
          requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
        }}
      />
    </View>

  );
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue stems from the emulator's performance, and to address it, I attempted to enhance its performance by increasing the allocated RAM and CPU cores, which significantly improved the situation.